# How to get grub2 to remember last choice?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

[Grub2 - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Saved) says the following:

> Saving an OS can be achieved by running sudo grub-set-default if
>   DEFAULT=saved is set in /etc/default/grub. It may also be saved if
>   GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true is also set in /etc/default/grub. In this case,
>   the default OS remains until a new OS is manually selected    from the
>   GRUB 2 menu or the grub-set-default command is executed.

I put the lines `DEFAULT=saved` AND `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` in `/etc/default/grub`, and ran `sudo grub-set-default`.  Here is the output:

```
$ sudo grub-set-default
entry not specified.
Usage: grub-set-default [OPTION] entry
Set the default boot entry for GRUB.

  -h, --help              print this message and exit
  -v, --version           print the version information and exit
  --boot-directory=DIR    expect GRUB images under the directory DIR/grub
                          instead of the /boot/grub directory

ENTRY is a number or a menu item title.

Report bugs to <bug-grub@gnu.org>.
```

Am I not following the documentation correctly?  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: After changing the grub file you best always run " `sudo update-grub`" .

Comment: Just run: sudo grub-set-default saved It's that simple.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

The documentation in this case is wrong. All variables in `/etc/default/grub` start with `GRUB_`, so the correct syntax is `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`, *not* `DEFAULT=saved`. I've corrected the Ubuntu wiki to reflect that.

The [official grub manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration) describes this correctly.
Put the following in `/etc/default/grub` (command line: `gedit admin:///etc/default/grub`):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: +1 for the link, I've edited your answer with the solution that worked for me (which I derived from the link you provided)

Comment: should I remove existing line `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` ?

Comment: @user25 yes remove `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`, the line should read `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`

Comment: I reboot into windows from linux using the above command. But now when i reboot from Windows, it defaults to windows and I cannot reboot from Windows into Linux

Comment: @revolutionary You can change it from boot options (F12) during boot.

Comment: If it's still not working for you double check you have `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT` and not `GRUB_SAVEDDEFAULT` (notice the extra 'D', it's not "saved_default", it's "save_default"). Been wondering why this wasn't working for me.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu Studio, the package 'ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings' forces the prioritization of the lowlatency kernel over the generic kernel, so you might be seeing that. If you uninstall that, it'll fix that, but you'll also lose "threadirqs" and other lowlatency optimizations.

My solution has been to use GRUB_DEFAULT=1, for example, instead of saved. I can't use the saved function without uninstalling this package

Answer (score 13):

In my case it was not working for entries defined via `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` which were missing the `savedefault` line.

```bash
menuentry "Chameleon" {
    savedefault ### <<<< this must be added
    set root="(hd1)"
    chainloader +1
}
```

Answer (score 5):

savedefault will not work, if there is no proper header in auto generated grub.cfg

To generate proper header you need set in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

and make grub-mkconfig to substitute your copy of grub.cfg

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub.cfg
```

savedefault from Grub 2.02 don't require any additional arguments

You could see source of savedefault in grub.cfg

Comment: Look at the answer from @ccpizza, may be this will help: https://askubuntu.com/a/674148/97838

Answer (score 4):

You are forgetting the number (ie. the "ENTRY is a number or a menu item title." in your text).

```
sudo grub-set-default 1
```

for option 1 to be the default.

**Always** run `sudo update-grub` after modifying the `/etc/default/grub` file to apply the changes.

Comment: This did not work for me, it just sets the GRUB menu to point to entry #1, not the last choice

Comment: If your menu option would be buried in a submenu, like within 'Advanced options for ubuntu', the format is 'submenu-index>submenu-item-index'. So you'd need to specify 1>'index-of-your-choice'. You are also supposed to be able to specify by string name for each selection.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [ccpizza](https://askubuntu.com/users/74172/ccpizza) I figured out, that my Windows-`menuentry` in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` was missing the `savedefault` Attribute:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
    savedefault    # <<<<<<<<<<<< THIS Attribute was missing!
    insmod ntfs
    insmod ntldr
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod search_fs_uuid
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root <WINDOWS_SSD_UUID>
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

In my case (Arch Linux, not Ubuntu ;) ) I found `pacman -S grub-customizer`  (from [this Post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422745/change-default-kernel-version-in-grub/44423201#44423201) of [matt-u](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3599086/matt-u)) which is a nice GUI Tool for customizing GRUB-Menu!

PS: I could neither upvote nor comment on [ccpizza](https://askubuntu.com/users/74172/ccpizza)'s answer because of missing credits in this forum, so I decided to give another answer :(

Comment: While the accepted answer is probably more relevant, this is what got my config running properly. Thanks!