# How can I back up a grub theme?

Tags: boot, grub2, themes, backup

A friend set up a really good grub configuation for my brother's laptop that has a backgound image. (It also autoselects the last option he chose during each boot)

There should be some way that I can pull these settings and apply them to my laptop correct? Can someone tell me where this stuff is located, how to apply it to another computer?

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you how to back up the background image.

> On your brother's laptop

1) Open a terminal and type: sudo -i (it will prompt for your password)
2) Enter in grub's folder: cd /boot/grub
3) List all visible files: ls -l
4) Find any file with image extension *.jpg, *.png, *.gif or *.tga (probably *.jpg)
5) Copy the image to usb hard drive:
      cp background_image.jpg /media/user_name/usb_hard_drive

> On your laptop

6) Repeat step 1)
7) Copy the image back from the usb hard drive to your grub folder: 
     cp /media/user_name/usb_hard_drive/background_image.jpg /boot/grub
8) Now reboot your laptop and it should load your image automatically.

And here you have how to save the last grub choice BUT be AWARE if you don't know what are you doing you can make your grub INACCESSIBLE!!!

[How to get grub2 to remember last choice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148662/how-to-get-grub2-to-remember-last-choice)