# booting into ubuntu from windows remotely

Tags: dual-boot, remote-desktop

I have remote access to my PC with Ubuntu and windows using teamviewer and google remote desktop. 
Sometimes, I need to remotely reboot from Windows to Ubuntu or from Ubuntu to Windows.
are there a way to do this.

- With vnc or team viewer you dont have acces to the grub menu when booting.
- can't edit the default boot entry from windows

thx

Comment: Please clarify what you mean "reboot from windows ...." it is unclear at the moment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

Comment: You need to change the default boot entry for grub and then reboot. So I think the answers in the linked question will help you although it's not a 100% duplicate I admit ... Also see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/834205/edit-grub-from-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit grub from Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834205/edit-grub-from-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have a iDrac,KVM,VPro,ILO you can reboot a running system and choose the booting OS. Or you mount your ubuntu in Windows with EXTFS and edit it before and reboot if your running OS is Windows and if it is Ubuntu you just change the default boot partition and reboot.