# How to switch back to default booting process?

Tags: boot

I have recently installed Ubuntu. I am really not sure what I pressed, but now it automatically boots up to recovery mode. I have to press ESC every time I boot to my account. Is there a way to make my system boot up to my account automatically every time I start up?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your grub is setup to always boot to a specific menu option. Taking this answer:

- [Edit grub from Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834205/edit-grub-from-windows/834406#834406)

You can always have grub remember the previous boot option each boot. Use `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`, comment the line below and insert two lines below it:

```
#GRUB_DEFAULT=0 # Rather than first menu option, we'll default to last  OS.
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Save the changes and run `sudo update-grub`.

The first time you boot **Recovery** will be the default option and you will need to press <kbd>Escape</kbd> again but now whatever option you select will be the default for the next boot.